# What is **Brahamana** in the Vedas and what is the role of them?

Tags: vedas

I want to know about the Brahmanas, I'm looking for help.

Comment: Also Newuser, can you add more on your question. Is there anything specific that you are looking for. What research have you done prior to asking this question on the topic?